# Exception for hashchange function - browser history back?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, hashchange

I have no idea how I should even call this problem … the title of this question doesn't make any sense at all, I know!

Following case: I have a single-page layout where users scroll downwards. I have sections `.layer` which, when inside the viewport should change the hash in the addressbar to its `id`. So e.g. the `.layer#one` is inside the viewport the url in the addressbar looks like this www.whatever.com/#!/one

```
$(window).scroll(function() {       
    hash = $('.layer:in-viewport').attr('id');
    top.location.hash = "!/" + hash;
});
```

This works just fine and is exactly like I want it. The reason I have this syntax with the `!/` is that if I would simply set the location to `hash` only the scroll-behaviour would be buggy because the browser tries to stick to the hash position.

The problem is now, that I want to be able to make browser history-back button working!
This would normally be rather simple with the `hashchange` function that comes with jQuery like so…

```
$(window).bind( 'hashchange', function( event ) {
    //query the hash in the addressbar and jump to its position on the site
});
```

The only problem I have with this is that the hashchange function would also be triggered if the hash is changed while scrolling. So it would again jump or stick to the current position in the browser. Any idea how I could solve this? I could probably unbind the hashchange while scrolling, right? But is this the best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you could just unbind and rebind whenever the hash changes on scroll. For example:

```
var old_hash;

var scroller = function() {       
    hash = $('.layer:in-viewport').attr('id');

    if ( old_hash != hash ) {
      $(window).off('hashchange', GoToHash); // using jQuery 1.7+ - change to unbind for < 1.7
      top.location.hash = "!/" + hash;

      setTimeout(function() { // ensures this happens in the next event loop
        $(window).on('hashchange', GoToHash);
      }, 0);

      old_hash = hash;
    }
}

var GoToHash = function() {
  //query the hash in the addressbar and jump to its position on the site
}

$(window).scroll(scroller);
```

Comment: hmm, thank you for this approach. Looks really good, however I can't seem to make it work. I posted my code to a jsfiddle, but the demo does of course not work on the jsfiddle website. http://jsfiddle.net/JDpqs/

Comment: BTW if you can afford to use pushState/onpopstate, it'd be great for this.

Comment: Yes I'm of course including it. I does already work with. Just the hashchange thing does not. If I use your script I have the same problem I had before, that the scrolling behaviour would be interrupted because as the hash changes the function fires and the browser tries to jump to the hash in the current viewport!

Comment: What do you mean by "if you can afford to use pushState/onpopstate"? Didn't actually know it existed. Have just no idea how this would work then. Of course I'd use a new html5 technology for this project!

Comment: Sorry, typo. Fixed my answer. Otherwise, by "afford" I meant to ask if you need to support browsers that don't include pushState support. If not, go for it!

Comment: thank you, works just great now! Have no idea how the pushstate thingy works. If it's not too tough I'll give it a try.

Comment: It's incredibly easy. See here if you haven't already: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState().C2.A0method . Create another question if you have problems and notify me – I'll help in exchange for more votes. :-)